# MIN With CASE expression

Tags: mysql, sql

When i execute this query, i can get 4 rows

```
select case WHEN bt.observedValue is null THEN 0
ELSE 1 END as selected
from tbl_billing_result b
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_test_details lt ON lt.billingId = b.id
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_sub_testdetails bt ON bt.billingTestDetailsId = lt.id
where b.id = 70
```

but i need to take min value from that 'selected' list. What is the exact query for that??
i tried below query but error is 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

```
SELECT 
min((
select case WHEN bt.observedValue is null THEN 0
ELSE 1 END as selected
from tbl_billing_result b
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_test_details lt ON lt.billingId = b.id
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_sub_testdetails bt ON bt.billingTestDetailsId = lt.id
where b.id = 70))
```

Comment: Why do you use a pair of `((` and `))` around subquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need another `SELECT`, just put `MIN()` around the `CASE` expression.

```
select MIN(case WHEN bt.observedValue is null THEN 0
                ELSE 1 END) as selected
from tbl_billing_result b
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_test_details lt ON lt.billingId = b.id
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_sub_testdetails bt ON bt.billingTestDetailsId = lt.id
where b.id = 70
```

You can also use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`:

```
select case WHEN bt.observedValue is null THEN 0
            ELSE 1 END as selected
from tbl_billing_result b
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_test_details lt ON lt.billingId = b.id
INNER JOIN tbl_billing_result_sub_testdetails bt ON bt.billingTestDetailsId = lt.id
where b.id = 70
ORDER BY selected
LIMIT 1
```